# homeomorphism between $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ and the Cantor Middle third set

Tags: general-topology, cantor-set, product-space

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_space), under the Section 'Example', the following function $$\sum_{n \geq 0}{\frac{2a_n}{3^{n+1}}}$$ is given as a homeomorphism between $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ and the Cantor Middle third set.

I don't see the motivation behind this function. Can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One definition of the Cantor set is that it is that subset of $[0,1]$ consisting of all those numbers whose ternary expansion contains no $1$s (can you see why?).  In other words, they contain only $0$s and $2$s.  So we can identify an element of $2^\mathbb N$ with an element of the Cantor set by mapping $0$s to $0$s in the ternary expansion and $1$s to $2$s in the ternary expansion.  For example:

$$
(0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,\dots)\mapsto 0.002202200022202\dots_3
$$

where the expansion is in ternary.  This is precisely the function that you have given.  It turns out that it is a homeomorphism.